# How can I check windows firewall status on remote server via C#

Tags: c#, windows, firewall

How can I check windows firewall status on remote server via C# ?

I Have investigated using a WMI call, but the Root/SecurityCenter2 only holds third party firewall information and I haven't been unable to find the Windows Firewall Information.

It seems that searching the registry may be the next choice, but before I went down this path I wanted to see if anyone else had any other ides/suggestions or code samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I did is using PSexec in order to execute the command of firewall:

```
Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = path; //the path of PsExec.exe
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\" + ip + " netsh advfirewall show domain state "; //you can change domain for allprofile in order to look for all profile firewall information
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output)
        if (output.Contains("ON"))
        {
           "Domain Firewall enabled";
        }else{
           "Domain Firewall disabled";
        }
```

PsExec :
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx
Just get the PsExec.exe

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) + "\\Resources\\PsExec.exe";
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\" + ip + " netsh advfirewall show domain state ";
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        if (output.Contains("ON"))
        {
            object[] rowResult = { "0", "Server Info", "Domain Firewall enabled, it should be disabled." };
            resultList.Add(rowResult);
        }
        else
        {
            object[] rowResult = { "1", "Server Info", "Domain Firewall disabled." };
            resultList.Add(rowResult);
        }
        return resultList;
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? Code-only answers are liable to be deleted because they don't have a wider currency by helping others understand the steps which led to you reaching your answer, and hence apply it to their own problems in future.

Comment: Sure, Basically I used PsExec (program that execute cmd commands) on C# and then use the Process Library to create a process where I can pass the parameters to PsExec, for example:
"\\10.0.0.0 netsh advfirewall show domain state" will show you the state of your domain firewall on your cmd, so use this as Process arguement and it will automatically execute it through PsExec, then use the process standartoutput.readToEnd() function in order to retrieve the information of the output.

Comment: Thanks for all your help

Comment: ... out of interest, why did you post three answers to this question?